# xlsxwriter is creating a corrupted file

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm using this code to test xlswriter functionnalitues.

```
    import xlsxwriter 
# -*- coding: utf-8-sig-*-
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("filename.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.add_table(0,0, 1, 11,{'columns': [{'header': 'ID'},
                                          {'header': '1'},
                                          {'header': u'ééé'},
                                          {'header': 'M'},
                                          {'header': 'C'},
                                          {'header': 'P'},
                                          {'header': u'o'},
                                          {'header': 'Pe'},
                                          {'header': 'F'},
                                          {'header': u'l'},
                                          {'header': 'C'},
                                          {'header': 'f'}
                                          ]})
workbook.close()
```

Excel is complaining about the file being corrputed. If I accept the repair I got the content as expected.

Update:
I have the same problem with this minimalistic code:

```
import xlsxwriter 



workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("filename.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("hi")
worksheet.add_table(0,0, 1, 2,{'columns': [{'header': 'ID'},
                                          {'header': '1'},
                                          {'header': '1'}]})
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/65 ?

Comment: Yep, I tried also without special chars like "é" and I got the same problem

Comment: Umm... I can't see anything obviously wrong (but then I'm not an 'xlswriter' expert) - but if you don't get an answer here - the developers have an active [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python-excel) they can be reached at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue in the second example is that Excel doesn't allow you to have two table headers with the same case-insensitive value ("1" in this case). The following works:

```
import xlsxwriter 

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("filename.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("hi")

worksheet.add_table(0, 0, 1, 2,{'columns': [{'header': 'ID'},
                                            {'header': '1'},
                                            {'header': '2'}]})
workbook.close()
```

There should be a warning from XlsxWriter about this but I wasn't aware of it until now. I'll add a check in an upcoming release. (Tracked on Github as [issue #362](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/362).)

This also looks like the issue in the first example since you have two headings called `'C'` and `'F'`/`'f'` - Excel requires header names to be case insensitively unique.